# Buy x Get Y Free - Not Working

Tags: promotions

We are running a promo for a specific brand where if you buy 3 of a specific style chair you get 1 free. This is what I have set up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkqrU.png

There are lots of colour variations of the chair so I have input all the skus, as it didn't work when I used the SKU of the default product that they are all associated with. I also changed the 'x' to 3 as I wasn't sure if it meant 3 or 4, but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento does not support it. I suggest that you try the [Amasty Special Promotions Pro](https://goo.gl/jYPgcS).

Amasy Special promotions pro really works for this kind of scenario.

You can find the other answer from here: [Buy 2 get 1 free for the same Category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201311/buy-2-get-1-free-for-the-same-category)

Answer (score 0):

Below extension links allow you to add free product to your cart. To do allow this, a new action "add a gift" is added to the cart price rules.

https://github.com/code4business/freeproduct