# Buy 2 get 1 free for the same Category

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

We want the cheapest product to be free when 3 or more products in the same category added in the cart. See instance below:

```
Cart Items:
Qty: 2 - Prod 1 - Price: 20 - Total: 40 - Cat 1
Qty: 1 - Prod 2 - Price: 10 - Total: 10 - Cat 2
Qty: 5 - Prod 3 - Price: 10 - Total: 50 - Cat 1 <- cheapest

Total: $100
```

So we want to offer 1 quantity free to `Prod 3` only since it's the cheapest item in the cart. So, we offer `$10` discount based on `Prod 3`.

Is this possible with Magento Promotions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Magento doesn't offer such a promotion in the standard.
You need to do it programmatically.

This might be useful for you:

[GITHUB Meabed - Magento buy x get the cheapest y for free](https://github.com/Meabed/magento-buy-x-get-the-cheapest-y-for-free)

If you're not into programming, you can get the ready extension from the internet.

Example one:

[Amasty Special Promotions Pro](https://goo.gl/jYPgcS)

Comment: We tried both, the Github works, but we found,] that [Amasty Special Promotions](https://goo.gl/jYPgcS) works the best for our needs.